# Finding the most popular words in a list

Tags: python, string, list, words

I have a list of words:

```
words = ['all', 'awesome', 'all', 'yeah', 'bye', 'all', 'yeah']
```

And I want to get a list of tuples:

```
[(3, 'all'), (2, 'yeah'), (1, 'bye'), (1, 'awesome')]
```

where each tuple is...

```
(number_of_occurrences, word)
```

The list should be sorted by the number of occurrences.

What I've done so far:

```
def popularWords(words):
    dic = {}
    for word in words:
        dic.setdefault(word, 0)
        dic[word] += 1
    wordsList = [(dic.get(w), w) for w in dic]
    wordsList.sort(reverse = True)
    return wordsList
```

The question is...

Is it Pythonic, elegant and efficient?
Are you able to do it better?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this.

```
import collections
words = ['all', 'awesome', 'all', 'yeah', 'bye', 'all', 'yeah']
counter = collections.Counter(words)
print(counter.most_common())
>>> [('all', 3), ('yeah', 2), ('bye', 1), ('awesome', 1)]
```

It gives the tuple with reversed columns.

From the comments: collections.counter is >=2.7,3.1. You can use [the counter recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) for lower versions.

Comment: Only in Python 2.7+ or 3.1+. Neither are widely used yet, so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: You can use [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) if you still use an older python version. I think it gives the same interface.

Comment: My tuples have reversed columns just because it was simpler for me to sort it. :) I like you answer as it is very elegant and I don't mind using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

The defaultdict collection is what you are looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(int)
for word in words:
    D[word] += 1
```

That gives you a dict where keys are words and values are frequencies. To get to your (frequency, word) tuples:

```
tuples = [(freq, word) for word,freq in D.iteritems()]
```

If using Python 2.7+/3.1+, you can do the first step with a builtin `Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter
D = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it Pythonic, elegant and efficient?

Looks good to me...

> Are you able to do it better?

"better"? If it's understandable, and efficient, isn't that enough?

Maybe look at [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to use that instead of setdefault.

Comment: I'm a Python student, learning everyday. Any tips, pieces of good advice are welcome.

Comment: BTW: defaultdict made my day!